# bash - command not found when parsing a text file with commands

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, quoting

I've got a text file composed of different commands:

```
set +e; false; echo $?
(false;   echo foo); echo \ $?
for i in .; do (false; echo foo); echo \ 1:$?; done; echo \ 2:$?
```

and so on.

I want to test these commands line-by-line, as a whole, in a bash child process using `set -e`, then check the error code from the parent bash process to see if the child exited with an error. I'm stuck on how to process the simpler commands (e.g. the first one listed above). Here's one of my recent attempts:

```
mapfile file < "$dir"/errorData
bash -c "${file[0]}"
echo $?
```

returns

```
bash: set +e: command not found  
bash:  false: command not found  
bash:  echo 127: command not found
```

I've tried several variants without luck. Using `bash -c \'"${file[1]}"\'` leads to one error message about command not found, with the above three strings now combined into one long string. Of course, simply wrapping the file commands in strong quotes and feeding them directly to `bash` in an interactive shell works fine.

Edit: I'm using bash 4.4.12(1)

Comment: I can't reproduce those errors on Bash v4.3.48. Everything works fine.

Comment: Are you sure you want to execute (-c) "${file[0]}", or did you mean to source it rather with . "${file[0]}" ?

Comment: @yacc Without -c, the command fails because bash is expecting a file or directory.

Comment: @randomir I don't track version updates frequently enough to comment on that. These error messages appear whether reading the commands from a script or entering them interactively one line at a time.

Comment: What do you get when you put: echo "${file[0]}" ??

Comment: This: set +e; false; echo $?

Comment: Then bash wants to execute 'false; echo $?' and that fails, bc the cmd doesn't exist. You need to tokenize that string again.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to successfully tokenize that example?

Comment: What about echo "${file[0]}" > $tmpfile && . $tmpfile ? I think bash -c `echo "${file[0]}"` could also work. Just guessing since I don't have bash handy.

Comment: line 11: $'false; echo $?\n': command not found

Comment: what's the exact content of $tmpfile?

Comment: It's empty, because the LHS of the redirection fails with a "$'false; echo $?\n': command not found" error. The other command doesn't fail but also doesn't fill the tmpfile with anything.

Comment: I meant you to add this line: `echo "${file[0]}" > $tmpfile && . $tmpfile`

Comment: Gotcha. That gives: 

temp: line 1: set +e: command not found  
temp: line 1:  false: command not found  
temp: line 1:  echo 127: command not found'.   

The content of the file is 'set +e; false; echo $?'

Comment: What if you put `set +e` on a single line and source the tmpfile again? Like this 1st line: `set +e` 2nd line: `false; echo $?`

Comment: temp: line 1: set +e: command not found. temp: line 2:  echo 1: command not found

Comment: Looks like bash fails to tokenize the `set +e`. This could mean that IFS has been tampered with. I'd like to continue with my work now since I've been on a break. I'll check back laters maybe. Good luck.

Comment: I'd think so too, but changing the value of IFS doesn't persist between new bash sessions. It's not tampered with in the script.

Comment: Just try a `IFS=" "` and check again. Good hunting.

Comment: @yacc It turns out the input text had a non-break space (U+00A0) rather than a space (U+0020). Just thought you might be interested in knowing. Thanks again for all the advice.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who finds that the shell is parsing their text in ways that seem to violate the reference manual, make sure to check any copied input data for invisible control characters. E.g. I found a non-breaking space in place of what looked like simple whitespace, in the input file with commands to be executed. This is especially common when copying from web pages to an editor or the command line. bash uses whitespace, tabs, and newlines to tokenize, not the non-breaking space (U+0020 in the Unicode standard). A hex editor, e.g. hexfiend, can help troubleshoot similar issues.

Comment: Your pasted data does not contain any non-breaking spaces (U+0020 is a regular space, U+00A0 is a non-breaking space). This is one of many reasons why it's a good idea to always copy your test case into a new directory and run it.

Comment: I typed the data you see here, because it was just a sample of several dozen lines. I pasted the actual data I was using.